# Use Different port for Different IP bind

Tags: ubuntu, bind

I am using bind for internal networking it is working good,

now I am a another requirement.

bind9 resolving the domain myweb.example.com from ip 192.168.1.1 port 80

now I want to resolve domain myweb.example.com:82 from 192.168.1.2:82.

is that possible?

Comment: DNS does *not* resolve ports (except for IN SRV request). Is resolves names and adresses.

Answer (score 2):

No. DNS is only about mapping host names to IP addresses, except for SRV records, but these can only be used in very specific circumstances with apps supporting this.

What is your end goal? Could a reverse proxy help you? With that, you would have one frontend server that listens both on port 80 and 82 and then delegates requests for one or both ports to a different backend server.

Comment: i have apache server on machine 192.168.1.1 and now I installed iis on 192.168.1.2 using port 82, we need to use same domain for both ip, so user will not confuse because this used by same application

Comment: Use a reverse proxy. Search for it, this is simple.

Comment: Ok, i will search for it